# Android Captured Image saved as Mirrored

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camera-intent, android-camerax

```
val outputOptions = ImageCapture
        .OutputFileOptions
        .Builder(photoFile)
        .setMetadata(ImageCapture.Metadata().also {
            it.isReversedHorizontal = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT == lensFacing
        }).build()

imageCapture.takePicture(
                    outputOptions, cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                        override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                        }

                        override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                            val savedUri = output.savedUri ?: Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                            Log.d(TAG, "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri")
                        }
                    })
```

While View image its Working fine , But while Save in local its not Working Fine, its in Mirror. Kindly help on this

Answer (score 1):

It's mirrored because you ask it to mirror it for the front camera. Simply remove this:

```
.setMetadata(ImageCapture.Metadata().also {
            it.isReversedHorizontal = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT == lensFacing
        }
```

Comment: No its not Worked,

Comment: Is it not working when opening the image in your app? Have you tried using Google Photo to open the image? If you create a minimal reproducible sample on GitHub, I can take a look.

Comment: in some device portrait image is shown as portrait mode and in another device portrait mode got rotated in 90 degree

Comment: Yes some device rotate the image while others don't. But CameraX should fix that with Exif. It might be the image viewer's issue not displaying the Exif correctly. Is Google Photo working for the images?